# Heroku app deploys on heroku but dns redirect brings up page saying there's nothing there

Tags: heroku, dns

my app launches on heroku adress...
[secret-brushlands](https://secret-brushlands-43080.herokuapp.com/)

but when I pointed my domain from my old host to where the app is on heroku I get [a heroku page](http://www.hypochondriacmd.com/) that just says nothing is here.

I followed the Heroku documents and pointed my DNS to the `xxx.herokudns.com` link they gave me on the settings page. The fact that i come up with a heroku page at all and not my previous placeholder wordpress page i had at that domaine name before tells me it is redirecting.

Any idea why my app is not at the address they told me to direct the name to?

Answer (score 0):

To make your Heroku-App work with your custom domain you have to do two things:

1. set the `CNAME` record (or `ANAME`, for that matter) to `secret-brushlands-43080.herokuapp.com` or `secret-brushlands-43080.herokudns.com`
2. add the custom domain to your application on Heroku through `heroku domains:add` or the dashboard.

Comment: curious then why the '.herokudns.com' it gave me was a completely different name (I thought it strange that it was not secret-brushlands

Comment: you should use whatever they give you in the interface, or the `heroku domains` command. 

I had the impression you didn't do the second step

Answer (score 0):

so I ended up opening a ticket with Heroku and they said my DNS was not pointed correctly. I went back (again) to my old host who I had the domain name with and the said it was done right this time. It seems not everything was pointed correctly on their end by the first tech (I know very little about DNS, so i was using the free support chat).

Basically everyhting i was told to do here in this thread was right, the mix up was on the DNS oint. So hopefully if anyone reads this later they can follow the steps above